# Select a word that is contained in database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to lock the registration of the user if their name contains some string insert into a table of database. I used this code:

```
$repWor =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reportedWord WHERE Word LIKE '%$username%'");

if (strpos($username, $repWor) !== false) {
    echo 'The name contains characters or words not allowed.';
}
```

But it doesn't work. How to fix it?

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions. They are removed as of PHP 7.0

Comment: Also make sure to fix that security hole you've got going on there... read more about SQL injection [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/mysql_query. mysql_query returns a statement handle, not a string you can search.

Comment: I will fix sql injection later, first I want to make the base of my site.

Comment: I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."* or *"Security isn't important now..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later?

Comment: what I can use instead mysql_query?

Comment: Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: @Cos8o `mysqli_*` is easier to migrate to from `mysql_*` (since they're almost identical in their APIs), but PDO is a lot easier to work with.

Comment: There's an answer to your question. If it's useful, you can click the checkmark to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

After the query you need to use something like `mysql_fetch_array` :

```
<?php
$repWor = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reportedWord WHERE Word LIKE '%$username%'",$cnx);

$dat = mysqli_fetch_array( $repWor ); // <====================

if (strpos($username, $dat["Word"] ) !== false) { echo 'The name contains characters or words not allowed.';
?>
```

As @apokryfos said, you should change to `mysqli`, it's easy :

```
<?php

$repWor = mysqli_query($cnx,"SELECT * FROM reportedWord WHERE Word LIKE '%$username%'");

$dat = mysqli_fetch_array( $repWor ); // <===================

if (strpos($username, $dat["Word"] ) !== false) { echo 'The name contains characters or words not allowed.';

?>
```

Comment: you forgot the connection handle in mysqli_query, so no... it's not as easy as just adding an `i` to the function call name.

Comment: You cannot just switch the to the `mysqli_*` functions. Some of them, including the connection, require a different syntax.

Comment: Please don't guess.

Answer (score 1):

Using mysql_query returns a result resource. It does not return a string or array based on your SQL. You must use mysql_query with a combination of mysql_fetch_row or mysql_fetch_assoc.

A full example can be found at
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

This then turns your code into:

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$query  = "SELECT * FROM reportedWord WHERE Word LIKE '%{$search}%'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
$row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if (strpos($username, $row['reportedWord']) !== false) {
    echo 'The name contains characters or words not allowed.';
}
```

You have a long way to go before getting a robust solution and you should perhaps consider using mysqli and follow the quick start guide: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php

Or go even further and use a  library such as Doctrine http://www.doctrine-project.org/

Comment: If I put "motherf--ker" it work, but if I put something like "123motherf--ker123" it doesn't work. Maybe there are some problem with the "%"?